# Is it possible to read an .mdb MS Access database in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access, odoo, odoo-8

I am working on Odoo 8, just wanted to know whether we can read an MS Access Database file in python 2.7 on Odoo.

Is there any other way to connect to MS Access and get data from it.(MS Access database is on a remote server)

Working Environment, python 2.7 Odoo in Linux Ubuntu. Really confused. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @Gord Thompson, First of all Thank you very much for referring me to your answer, but i am getting certain errors such as no module named zxJdbc, please kinidly guide on the setup part.Thank you very much

Comment: or no module named com.ziclix.python.sql is the erro